# Dynamic linear interpolation between multiple HTML input field values with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms, events

I'm trying to make a dynamically generated array of input fields where only the first and the last are editable. When either of the border fields are modified, the remaining should update their values by linearly interpolating between the two border values. Example below.

[image]

I have written a (Django/Bootstrap) HTML template which generates the input fields themselves, and leaves only the border fields editable and assigns "-first" and "-last" id extensions.

I have also written a basic JavaScript which takes two input values to interpolate between and output array size.

This is how the input fields are instantiated. I started writing a JS function "change_values()" which would be activated on onchange event, but got nowhere.

```
<div class="custom-control custom-linspace-field">
  <div class="row" id="linspace-field">
    {% for field in fields %}
    <div class="col p-1">
      {% if forloop.first %}
      <input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="change_values()" id="linspace-field-first" value="{{ field | floatformat:3 }}" placeholder="min">
      {% elif forloop.last %}
      <input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="change_values()" id="linspace-field-last" value="{{ field | floatformat:3 }}" placeholder="max">
      {% else %}
      <input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="change_values()" id="linspace-field" value="{{ field | floatformat:3 }}" readonly>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my linear interpolation JS script:

```
function lerp(value1, value2, amount) {
    step = (value2 - value1) / amount;
    output = [value1];
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < amount; i++) {
      output.push(output[output.length - 1] + step);
    }
    output.push(value2);
    output_round = [];
    output.forEach(function(item) {
      output_round.push(item.toFixed(2));
    });
    return output_round;
  }
```

I am hoping to find a way to access input field values in the correct order and update them whenever an onchange event is triggered on either of the border input fields.

Basically my question is: what should the code for the change_values() function called on the onchange event look like?

Comment: First of all, you should not have multiple elements with the same `id` value in your html.

Comment: @HelgeFox funnily enough, your comment pointed me in the right direction towards solving this. I checked what the `id` parameter is actually for, and realized that I could generate a unique ID for each of the input fields with their respective index, and then sort them out appropriately in a JS function.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @HelgeFox for pointing out that I shouldn't have identical id tags in my HTML. This made me realize that I can use those to dynamically assign unique IDs upon creation of the input fields and then use them to assign interpolated values.

```html
{% for field in some_list_with_enumerated_initial_values %}
<div class="col p-1">
  {% if forloop.first %}
  <input type="number" step="0.05" class="form-control" onchange="change_fields()" id="linspace-field-{{ field.0 }}" value="{{ field.1 }}" placeholder="min">
  {% elif forloop.last %}
  <input type="number" step="0.05" class="form-control" onchange="change_fields()" id="linspace-field-{{ field.0 }}" value="{{ field.1 }}" placeholder="max">
  {% else %}
  <input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="change_fields()" id="linspace-field-{{ field.0 }}" value="{{ field.1 | floatformat:3 }}" readonly>
  {% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Here are the JS functions I used.

```js
function lerp(value1, value2, amount) {
    // Calculate what the interpolation step will be.
    step = (value2 - value1) / amount;
    // Create an array where all the interpolated values will be added. Add the first value.
    output = [value1];
    var i;
    // Start with i = 1 so that the last element would not be added.
    for (i = 1; i < amount; i++) {
      output.push(output[output.length - 1] + step);
    }
    // The last element is added here, because this way it is certain that the last value will match value2 in arguments.
    output.push(value2);
    // Round all elements before returning
    output_round = [];
    output.forEach(function(item) {
      output_round.push(item.toFixed(2));
    });
    return output_round;
  }

  function change_fields() {
    // Create an array with all the "linspace-field" elements.
    var fields = $('*[id^="linspace-field"]');
    // Create another array with the new set of values. They are stored as strings and need to be parsed.
    var lerp_values = lerp(parseFloat(fields[0].value), parseFloat(fields[fields.length - 1].value), fields.length - 1)
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
      // Replace each of the values in "linspace-field" elements.
      fields[i].value = lerp_values[i];
    }
  }
```